# Using sed to remove all lines that don't match a pattern

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Very new (meaning a day) to sed.  I have worked a way to remove the lines that I do not need for an updated file with find/replace of a singular command

I have a list of objects as follows from a fortigate configuration:

```
config firewall address <--keep line
edit "item1"
next
edit "item2"
next
edit "item3"
next
edit "item4" <--keep line
unset associated-interface <--keep line and use as anchor for one line above and below
next <--keep line
edit "item5" <--keep line
unset associated-interface <--keep line and use as anchor for one line above and below
next <--keep line
edit "item6"
next
end <--keep line
```

I am trying to have it so when it is all said and done I am trying to keep the three lines (item4 & item5) and remove all of the other lines.  Also, if possible keep the first and last line.

Comment: What's the expected output? How does the way you've found so far not do what you expect it to?

Comment: Is there a reason you avoid using `head`, `tail` and `grep -v`?

Comment: It would leave the first and last line and items 4 & 5

Comment: No reason Shloim, lack of knowledge.  But if you have any ideas that would be great!

Comment: It would help if you could clearly identify which lines you want to keep - perhaps put `<==` alongside those lines?

Comment: Gem, added your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your description lacks a great deal of precision, but here goes *something*:

```
sed -n -e '/^config/p;/item[45]/p;/^end/p' forti
config firewall address
edit "item4"
edit "item5"
end
```

**Edit**: this answer was given 2 hours before the edit that required the lines up to and following `next` after the `item4` and `item5` to be kept...

Comment: I'm surprised that `sed -n '/<something>/p'` was not the first answer in the list ...

Comment: Not sure what you mean @eurythmia ? :)

Comment: derp ... I read the times backwards ... this was the first answer ... I just would have expected to see it at the top because ... well, this is the exact use case that `sed -n` was made for :-P

Comment: Thanks for the input but the output takes too many lines out that are required for the file to function properly.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/config/,/end/!d;/config/b;/end/b;/item4/,+2b;/item5/,+2b;d' file
```

Delete all lines not between `config` and `end`. Print lines that begin `config` or `end` and lines that start with `item4` or `item5` and the following two lines.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best way to do it, but I couldn't find any other way around it.

I narrowed it down to four commands, which you can put in a bash script (replace `file.txt` with your own source file, and `/tmp/finalFile` with whatever destination you need):

```
head -n1 file.txt >> /tmp/finalFile
head -n $(echo $(grep -ni item6 file.txt | cut -d: -f1) - 1 | bc) file.txt > /tmp/tmpfile
tail -n $(echo $(wc -l /tmp/tmpfile | awk '{print $1}') - $(grep -n item4 /tmp/tmpfile | cut -d: -f1) + 1 | bc) /tmp/tmpfile >> /tmp/finalFile
tail -n1 file.txt >> /tmp/finalFile
```

When I ran the above commands, this is the final file in `/tmp/finalFile`:

```
config firewall address 
edit "item4" 
unset associated-interface  
next 
edit "item5" 
unset associated-interface 
next 
end
```

Some explanation:

- The first line is simply the top line grabbed by `head`, appended to `finalFile`
- The second step is basically look for every line up to `item5`, and save that in a temp file.
- The third step grabs that temp file, and calculates how many lines it needs to `tail`, to get all the lines up to `item6`, not including it, and grabs those lines, appending the output to `finalFile`.
- Finally, the last line grabs the last line from the original file with `tail`, and appends that to `finalFile`

Comment: mjuarez, thanks for the input and this does work but how would you use this and use the "associated-interface" as an anchor to keep the line above and below.  Everything else works as expected.  Was not aware of the "head" tool and will look into that as well.